# How to format json in rails controller?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

How to format json in rails controller? Via link_to i'm sending and get in method params[:cat], then i fetch all childrens via parent (params[:cat]), but how to format this all in json format for my jqTree? So it looks like {label : (here goes params[:cat]), children: [{all @search_trees.id}]} ?

```
require 'json'
        @search_trees = SearchTree.find(:all, :include => [:designation], :conditions => { :STR_ID_PARENT => params[:cat]})
        #data = "{ label : '10001',  children : [{label : '10111'},{label : '10122'}]  }"
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @search_trees }
          format.json { render :json => data }
        end
```

I'll fetch a part of question from my long question here:

> [How to correctly do jquery tree in rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728782/how-to-correctly-do-jquery-tree-in-rails-app)

Her is my json:

> [{"search_tree":{"STR_DES_ID":42275,"STR_ID":10130,"STR_ID_PARENT":10726,"STR_LEVEL":4,"STR_NODE_NR":130,"STR_SORT":621,"STR_TYPE":1,"designation_id":42275}},{"search_tree":{"STR_DES_ID":42277,"STR_ID":10132,"STR_ID_PARENT":10726,"STR_LEVEL":4,"STR_NODE_NR":132,"STR_SORT":620,"STR_TYPE":1,"designation_id":42277}},{"search_tree":{"STR_DES_ID":43152,"STR_ID":10730,"STR_ID_PARENT":10726,"STR_LEVEL":4,"STR_NODE_NR":730,"STR_SORT":622,"STR_TYPE":1,"designation_id":43152}},{"search_tree":{"STR_DES_ID":42209,"STR_ID":12344,"STR_ID_PARENT":10726,"STR_LEVEL":4,"STR_NODE_NR":2344,"STR_SORT":623,"STR_TYPE":1,"designation_id":42209}}]
>   i need to output like this
>   [jqTree - creating tree data from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405222/jqtree-creating-tree-data-from-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize your json, you can use RABL or JBuilder. You will find screencasts here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?autoplay=true and here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl?autoplay=true.